# How to add button for specify position in Table View in I phone?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

you show this image

[image]

i need add button in 7 item to last in table view.
and i need every button's different `selector`.
this is possible?
**EDIT:** 
I need code that idea.

Comment: it's fix last 7 cell you want to add?

Comment: yes,and every button selfly work.

Comment: you mean last seven cell in the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes ofcourse ,keep condition in cellForRowAtIndexPath method, `indexPath.row>6` then add button otherwise left out.

Give tag value to the button and based on that tag value perform the different operations whatever you want.

place this one in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
if(indexPath.row>6){
 UIButton *checkBtnOne= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        checkBtnOne.frame=CGRectMake(10, 76, 21, 21);
        checkBtnOne.tag=indexPath.row;
        checkBtnOne.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_radio.png"]];
        [checkBtnOne addTarget:self action:@selector(radioButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell addSubview:checkBtnOne];

}

-(IBAction)radioButton:(id)sender{
    UIButton *checkBtn=(UIButton *)sender;
    // here you will get the tag value so based on that you can perform the action.
    if(checkBtn.tag==6)
       //first button
    else if (checkBtn.tag==7)
      //second button
    else if (checkBtn.tag==8)
      //third button
    .
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: ,i need that code for add button in table view and every added dynamic button selfly wrok.

Comment: ,-(IBAction)radioButton:(id)sender{
    UIButton *checkBtn=(UIButton *)sender;
    // here you will get the tag value so based on that you can perform the action.
} this code work only one button or added every button?

Comment: -(IBAction)radioButton:(id)sender{
    UIButton *checkBtn=(UIButton *)sender;
    // here you will get the tag value so based on that you can perform the action.
} @sunny how to work second buy button from this code.

Comment: @AnilMetatagg: check it now.

Answer (score 0):

In Cell for row at index path method of UITable View

check index `path.row > 6`
Add Button and set button `object.tag = index path.row`.
Thus you will find each button working individual with their tag value.
Don't forget to add target for added button and recieve tag value in added method for use button individually.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement two sections for the `UITableView`.

1. In first one you should use default cells with custom background
   image.
2. In second section you can use Custom subclass of `UITableViewCell` (With `UIButton` in it)

It will make your code cleaner.

For actions specific to second section's cells you can implement it using @Sunny's answer.